# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Mark up scale

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the markups core extension with the viewer but getting a strange issue with the markup sizes. The first time the markups go on they look correct but when another model is loaded into the viewer the markup lines are too big and trying to put an arrow on fills the entire viewer red. This problem persists until i clear the browser cache then it works again the first time and breaks the second time.
Anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We've heard about this issue in the past, and IIRC the problem was related to different model scales. The markup extension is basically updating the `<svg>` element's `viewBox` property and the line thickness of markups based on the scale of the underlying model. It's possible that the view-box and/or line thicknesses are not updated when switching to another model.

Please provide more information about your specific case (Forge Viewer version, exact repro steps, or a code snippet with sample models, etc.). If those cannot be shared publicly, feel free to share it with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (we will not share the information with anyone outside of Autodesk).

Comment: thanks Petr i will share more information with you via email and reference this post